# Get notification's from NSNotificationServer in C++ program

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

I'm creating a simple C++ application with cmake on Mac.
There is a main in C++ source code file, that create C++ class. Inside this class I'm allocating objective C object, that adding itself to observers in NSNotificationCenter. And I'm not receiving those notifications.
There is a code:

Notifications.h

```
class LaunchNotification {
public:
    LaunchNotification();
    virtual ~LaunchNotification();

    void StartNotifications();
    void StopNotifications();

private:
    void    *monitor;
};
```

Notifications.mm

```
@interface Monitor : NSObject
-(id) init;
-(void) appLaunchedNotification :(NSNotification *) notification;
-(void) appTerminatedNotification :(NSNotification *) notification;
@end

@implementation Monitor

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        count = 0;
        NSNotificationCenter *notCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

        [notCenter addObserver : self
            selector:@selector(appLaunchedNotification:)
            name:NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification
            object:nil];

        [notCenter addObserver : self
            selector:@selector(appTerminatedNotification:)
            name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification
            object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) appLaunchedNotification : (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSString *path = [[notification userInfo]objectForKey: @"NSApplicationPath"];
}

- (void) appTerminatedNotification : (NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSString *path = [[notification userInfo]objectForKey: @"NSApplicationPath"];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    NSNotificationCenter *notCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

    [notCenter removeObserver : self];

    [super dealloc];
}
@end

LaunchNotification::LaunchNotification() : monitor(NULL)
{}

LaunchNotification::~LaunchNotification()
{
    StopNotifications();
}

void LaunchNotification::StartNotifications()
{
    if (NULL == monitor)
    {
        monitor = [[Monitor alloc] init];
    }
}

void LaunchNotification::StopNotifications()
{
    if (NULL != monitor)
    {
        [(id)monitor release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a "run loop" in your application (NSRunLoop)?

Comment: As I understand it from reference don't need it ("Each NSThread object, including the application’s main thread, has an NSRunLoop object automatically created for it as needed.")

Comment: But you may have to "run" the loop. See the documentation of `-[NSRunLoop run]` for an example. Cocoa and iOS applications do that automatically, but not command-line tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a run loop because otherwise, NSWorkspace has no mechanism to gain control of your application's thread in order to post notifications.

While the docs say run loops are automatically created, they are **not** automatically executed.  Think about it:  how can a thread be simultaneously running your code and running the code in the run loop?

Any tasks that you need to do while you are monitoring the notification centre need to be done in the context of runloop events e.g. on an `NSTimer` event, or you need a separate thread for that other stuff.

Comment: @Ation Notifications are processed in the threads in which they are raised.  If the notification is raised in the main thread it will get processed in the main thread.  There are several other ways to make stuff happen in another thread e.g. `-performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` or `-performSelector:inBackgroundWithObject:` You can also use NSOperations or GCD.  Check out the [Concurrency Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).